# Trying to get a table to appear with Onclick

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi I have a table that looks like this which is mainly php but sadly i have to make it that way:

```
        if (!isset ($_SESSION['Saved_contacts']))   
            $Kontakte = array (
                array ("Hr.", "Fruehauf",   "Dennis", "13.02.2002", "Brucknerweg 34",  5212, "Hausen", '<a href="#" class="Fruehauf"><u>3.6</u></a>'),
                array ("Fr.", "Kaufmann",   "Katharina", "04.03.2002", "Neubertbogen 24", 1680, "Romont", "Durchschnitt"),
                array ("Hr.", "Fiedler",   "Marcel", "08.16.2002", "Via Stazione 98", 8143, "Stallikon", "Durchschinitt"),
                array ("Hr.", "Oster",   "Tim", "08.26.2002", "Via delle Vigne 98", 1773, "Vuaty", "Durchschinitt"),
                array ("Fr.", "Eichelberger",   "Tanja", "07.22.2002", "Semperweg 6", 4223, "Blauen", "Durchschinitt"));
        else                                        // Falls Session-Variablen bereits vorhanden => diese nehmen!
            $Kontakte = $_SESSION['Saved_contacts'];
    ?>



  <div style="width: 80%; min-width: 550px">
    <h2>Kontakt des Schülers ...</h2>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Nr.</th>
        <th>Anrede</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Vorname</th>
        <th>Geburtsdatum</th>
        <th>Adresse</th>
        <th>PLZ</th>
        <th>Ort</th>
        <th>Durchschnitt</th>
      </tr>
      <?php

        for ($i=0; $i < count($Kontakte); $i++) {   
            echo "<tr> <td><em>".($i+1)."</em></td>" . "<td style='text-align: center'>".$Kontakte[$i][0]."</td>" .
                      "<td>".$Kontakte[$i][1]."</td>" . "<td>".$Kontakte[$i][2]."</td>" . "<td>".$Kontakte[$i][3]."</td>" .
                      "<td>".$Kontakte[$i][4]."</td>" . "<td>".$Kontakte[$i][5]."</td>" . "<td>".$Kontakte[$i][6]."</td>" . "<td onclick=\"show(\"example\");\">".$Kontakte[$i][7]."</td>" . " <td></tr>";
        }
    ?>
    </table>
```

and Im trying to get this table:

```
<div class="Note">
  <div style="width: 80%; min-width: 550px">

    <table class="grade_Fruehauf" style="" id="example">
      <tr>
        <th>Fruehauf</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>Deutsch</th>
        <th>3.5</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>Math</th>
        <th>3.5</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>Biologie</th>
        <th>3.5</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>Französisch</th>
        <th>4</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>Durchschnitt</th>
        <th style="border-top:solid;">3.6
          <th>
      </tr>

    </table>
    <div>
    </div>
```

To appear via an onclick method with javascript so i used this code but for some reason it doesn't seem to work, im not sure if the show function in the table is not working or is the javascript code not working.

```
<script>
function show(example) {
  var x = document.getElementById(example);
  if (window.getComputedStyle(x).visibility === "hidden") {
    x.style.visibility = "visible";
  } else {
    x.style.visibility = "hidden";
  }
}
</script>
```

It has been already identified on the last line in the first table but for some reason it doesn't appear. Is my onclick code wrong?

Comment: @MarkBaijens I don't think that's relevant. It's the second table they're trying to show

Comment: Isn't this the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69526219/get-a-hidden-table-to-appear-with-with-a-click-with-php?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any Console errors in the browser?

Because if you echo

```
"<td onclick=\"show(\"example\");\">"
```

it will output

```
<td onclick="show("example");">
```

As you can see, the second `"` will end the `onclick` attribute, so JS will try to execute the command `show(` when the click occurs, which clearly isn't valid. I would expect it to cause a

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

error when you try to click on it.

You'd either need to escape the inner double-quotes, or more simply just use single-quotes round the string in JS, since it allows that:

```
<td onclick=\"show('example');\">"
```

will output

```
<td onclick="show('example');">
```

when you echo it.

---

Another, arguably neater alternative is to stop using old-fashioned inline event handlers, and start using `addEventListener` instead.

If you give your `<td>`s a class, you can then set one listener for them all, since it seems you want to open the same table for all of them (they're generated by a loop so I assume there will be several on the page):

HTML/PHP:

```
<td class="showTable">
```

Javascript

```
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   var tds = document.querySelectorAll(".showExample");
   tds.forEach(function(td) {
     td.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
       var x = document.querySelector("#example");
       if (x.style.visibility === "hidden") {
         x.style.visibility = "visible";
       } else {
         x.style.visibility = "hidden";
       }
     });
   });
 });
```

Also it would probably make more sense if the table was hidden initially.

Working demo:

```js
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   var tds = document.querySelectorAll(".showExample");
   tds.forEach(function(td) {
     td.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
       var x = document.querySelector("#example");
       if (x.style.visibility === "hidden") {
         x.style.visibility = "visible";
       } else {
         x.style.visibility = "hidden";
       }
     });
   });
 });
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td class="showExample">Example</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="showExample">Example</td></tr>
</table>

<div class="Note">
  <div style="width: 80%; min-width: 550px">

    <table class="grade_Fruehauf" style="visibility:hidden" id="example">
      <tr>
        <th>Fruehauf</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>Deutsch</th>
        <th>3.5</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>Math</th>
        <th>3.5</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>Biologie</th>
        <th>3.5</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>Französisch</th>
        <th>4</th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <th>Durchschnitt</th>
        <th style="border-top:solid;">3.6
        </th>
      </tr>

    </table>
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```